# jquery dialog: executing a .hide() on the main form doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

This is my code for the dialog:

```
                "Save": function () {
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");

                    if ($("#EventManage").valid()) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Home/EventSave",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: $("#EventManage").serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                //alert("s");
                                $("#EventManage").html(result);
                                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");
                                LoadEventList();
                                alert('x');
                                $('td.hide').hide(); <<<<<
                                alert('x');
                                $('#eventlistww').each(function () {
                                    var $table = $(this);
                                    $('tr', $table).each(function () {
                                        var $row = $(this);
                                        $('td', $row).each(function () {
                                            $('td.hide').hide();
                                        });
                                    });
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
```

I'm trying to get the $('td.hide').hide(); <<<<< to work on the main page. Not sure why it doesn't work, but it appears to work when I set that second alert('x'); after which it is executed. Without that alert, it doesn't work.

What went wrong?

**EDIT**

@ChrisFrancis strangely no, I comment out the 2nd part, and do that alert magic again. it works. without the alerts, it doesn't work.

**EDIT2**

Wish to add, the LoadEventList() looks like this:

```
function LoadEventList() {
         $("#eventlistww").load("/Home/EventDataList");
    }
```

**SEEMED TO GET MY ANSWER:**

I seemed to have got it working by changing the LoadEventList() instead.

```
function LoadEventList() {
        $.get('/Home/EventDataList', function (result) {
            $('#eventlistww').html(result);
            $('td.hide').hide();
        });
    }
```

strange though why this works but the .load method doesnt.

Comment: It sounds to me like the first `$('td.hide').hide()` statement isn't ever working - it just appears to work after the second alert because you then go on to call `$('td.hide').hide()` again.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis strangely no, I comment out the 2nd part, and do that alert magic again. it works. without the alerts, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think it must be a race condition then - the time it takes you to click 'OK' on the second alert could be allowing the DOM to render fully, whereas without it you might not have the element on the page yet. As Dominic pointed out below, make sure you're using the document ready event before performing any DOM manipulation.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis, how can I do a document ready within the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it could be a race condition. The document ready event is designed to circumvent these problems, and [jQuery makes this very simple](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  Simply wrap all of your example code inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* your code here... */
});
```

Or use one of the other syntactic variations as mentioned in the documentation - I prefer:

```
$(function() {
    /* your code here... */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be a little bit over-complicated.

Did you know you can use nested css-selectors instead of iterating each level (which doesn't seem to do anything since you call all td.hide in you loop anyway?)

Change:

```
 $('#eventlistww').each(function () {
                                    var $table = $(this);
                                    $('tr', $table).each(function () {
                                        var $row = $(this);
                                        $('td', $row).each(function () {
                                            $('td.hide').hide();
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
```

To

```
 $('#eventlistww tr td.hide').hide();
```

And make sure there's actually a matching element. An easy way would be to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or such.

Comment: same thing, with an alert before $('#eventlistww tr td.hide').hide(); it will work, after I clicked OK on that alert. without that alert, nothing hidden!

Comment: This is good advice - the nested selector is much cleaner, and actually your nested loops were redundant any way because the last call (`$('td.hide').hide();`) selects **ALL** DOM elements that match, not just those within the `$('td', $row)` selector...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using on document ready, also check your table markup if it is malformed you command will not work.

Broken example here http://jsfiddle.net/DVxSy/72/ no table tags
Working here http://jsfiddle.net/DVxSy/71/

Comment: The table markup looks fine to me. The table tags, tr and td all shows properly